Can mods see a tally of the warnings and suspensions a user has received, and is there a way for the user to see the same tally?
In a discussion in chat, a mod said

Phil is really not helping you - he had various warnings and suspensions for failing to follow site guidelines." (ref)

My question is about what a mod can see. Can they see a tally of the warnings and suspensions that a user has received along with the associated dates? Can they see this information across site boundaries or just within the context of the site that they are moderating?
If mods can see such tallies, is it possible for the user to see the same data, or request that it be sent to them privately?

How can I view the list of my suspensions on a given SE site?

Thanks! The previous question doesn't ask about warnings and doesn't ask about what mods can see by using mod tools. For the user part, the only answer is to write a script that scrapes your inbox for emails from mods. This suggests that the answer might be "No, users can't see a tally" but it's not explicate. Think I should edit the previous question or just leave his question as is?

Leaving the question as if is fine as indeed you're asking also to get the list as a mod


Can they see a tally of the warnings and suspensions that a user has received along with the associated dates?

Yes - suspensions are basically moderator messages, and we can view any moderator messages  sent to a user. The UI for accessing your own moderator messages is "dig through your inbox" - I've asked about it before. I don't think its ideal, but its what you got.

Can they see this information across site boundaries

No. Practically though, if we suspect a user's causing the same issues on another specific site, we can informally ask the moderators there to take a look. In nearly all cases, unless there's active, multi-site trolling, we're more concerned about a user's actions on our sites rather than their history

or just within the context of the site that they are moderating?

Yes

I'm a mod on two of our other sites and I can confirm that I can pull up a list of every time you were banned or warned by moderators. I can see the exact text of the message you were sent along with the ban length you were given (if any). I can only bring this up on sites where I'm a mod. The vast, vast majority of users have either one or zero notifications. A small number of users have a list a mile long. These are the users that earn year-long suspensions.

@RobertColumbia Thanks! If a user asked you for their banned/warned list, is there a way that you could share it with them privately?

We don't really have a PM system and we're strongly discouraged from sending emails. I guess a private chatroom might work but that's visible to every other moderator. Personally I'd rather have an easy way for users to view their own moderator messages easily without getting a mod to find a workaround. I'd be willing to share but the system's not designed for it to be 'easy'

@phil1008 yes, I could share it in a private chatroom upon request. I don't see any reason I wouldn't be willing to do that unless it was obvious that the request was in bad faith and the user just wanted a trophy.

Just a note that this answer is referring to the Q&A site. It's a little different for chat suspension, where all mods can see them on Chat.SE, but only MSE mods on Chat.MSE, and SO mods on Chat.SO.
